# Symfony 2 FOSUserBundle Relation to Products Table

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, entity-relationship, fosuserbundle

I apologize in advance if this has been asked before.

I have successfully setup FOSUserBundle.

I am trying to setup "http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html" the product example from that link out of the documentation.

What I would like to do is set it up so a specific user adds a product the User Id of the FOSUser that user is associated with that product.

I have two bundles in the Acme folder

Acme/UserBundle -> the FOSUser Setup

and

Acme/MainBundle -> where I am setting up products.

I've gone over the relationship documents a few time and I am not quite clear on them in Symfony2.

I think it is a OneToMany relationship in the User Entity based on a "user_id" in the Products table but i'm not a 100% sure how to do it.

Does anyone know a tutorial or even a basic idea on if I am going in the right direction on this? Thanks very much and I will obviously publish the successful results Once I get there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works perfectly for me in Symfony 2.3 I got it from Reading the docs and going the knpuniversities episode 3 on Symfony2 I hope it helps someone.

The Entity

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

use Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="products")
 */
class Products
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", scale=2)
     */
    protected $price;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    protected $description;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return Products
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set price
     *
     * @param float $price
     * @return Products
     */
    public function setPrice($price)
    {
        $this->price = $price;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get price
     *
     * @return float 
     */
    public function getPrice()
    {
        return $this->price;
    }

    /**
     * Set description
     *
     * @param string $description
     * @return Products
     */
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get description
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User", cascade={"remove"})
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(onDelete="CASCADE")
    */
   private $owner;

      public function getOwner()
    {
        return $this->owner;
    }

    public function setOwner(User $owner) 
    {
        $this->owner = $owner; 
    }
}
```

and in the Controller

```
 /**
     * Creates a new Products entity.
     *
     */
    public function createAction(Request $request)
    {
        $entity = new Products();
        $form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

           // Associate User Entity To Product 
            $user = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
            $entity->setOwner($user);

            $em->persist($entity);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('products_show', array('id' => $entity->getId())));
        }

        return $this->render('AcmeMainBundle:Products:new.html.twig', array(
            'entity' => $entity,
            'form'   => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have to add a relation between your user and your product. So your Product entity should be like this :

**src/Acme/MainBundle/Entity/Product.php**

```
namespace Acme\MainBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="product")
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", scale=2)
     */
    protected $price;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    protected $description;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="products")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $user;
}
```

And your user entity

**src/Acme/UserBundle/Entity/User.php**

```
namespace Acme\UserBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Acme\MainBundle\Entity\Product;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 */
class User
{
    /**-
     * User properties...
     */

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Acme\MainBundle\Entity\Product", mappedBy="user", cascade={"remove"})
     */
    protected $products;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->products = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Add product
     *
     * @param Product $product
     * @return Branch
     */
    public function addProduct(Product $product)
    {
        $this->products[] = $product;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove product
     *
     * @param Product $products
     */
    public function removeProduct(Product $product)
    {
        $this->products->removeElement($product);
    }

    /**
     * Get products
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getProducts()
    {
        return $this->products;
    }
}
```

Everything is explain in the [doctrine documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html)