# Symfony FOS and relationships

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I use FosUserBundle. I have Entity Packages and Order. I am trying to bind Order with fos_user.

I modeled on this site [Symfony 2 FOSUserBundle Relation to Products Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109270/symfony-2-fosuserbundle-relation-to-products-table)

User:

```
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;
...
```

Order:

```
namespace My\SaleBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use My\UserBundle\Entity\User;
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="order")
 */
class Order {
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;
    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="My\UserBundle\Entity\User", cascade={"remove"})
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(onDelete="CASCADE")
    */
    protected $user;
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Packages", inversedBy="id")
     */
    protected $package;

    /*... */

    /* Seetery i gettery */

    public function setUser(User $owner)
    {
        $this->user = $owner;
    }
    public function setPackage($val)
    {
        $this->package = $val;
    }
    /*... */
}
```

Controller:

```
        $usr= $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
        $order= new Order();
        $order->setUser($usr);
        /*... */
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($order);
        $em->flush();
```

I see: Unrecognized field: user_id

Answer (score 0):

According to this http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-joincolumn `name` and `referencedColumnName` is a required attribute for `@JoinColumn`

Change this

```
/**
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="My\UserBundle\Entity\User", cascade={"remove"})
* @ORM\JoinColumn(onDelete="CASCADE")
*/
protected $user;
```

to

```
/**
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="My\UserBundle\Entity\User", cascade={"remove"})
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
*/
protected $user;
```

Comment: I tried add name. It doesn't help. I changed it and nothing

Comment: Maybe It's help.

<pre> at ORMException ::unrecognizedField ('user_id') 
in /var/www/public_html/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/BasicEntityPersister.php at line 1681   + 
at BasicEntityPersister ->getSelectConditionStatementColumnSQL ('user_id', null) 
in /var/www/public_html/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/BasicEntityPersister.php at line 1610   + 
at BasicEntityPersister ->getSelectConditionStatementSQL ('user_id', '2', null) 
in /var/www/public_html/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/BasicEntityPersister.php at line 1701</pre>

Comment: did you update your schema after changing the mappings?

Comment: Ofc. But I don't understand, why doctrine didn't see changes. I had delete table "order". Maybe is mistake in entity user? I didn't add a column "owner".

Comment: Do you have a field caller `user_id` in your `order` table?

Comment: Its may be coming from somewhere else.. Try isolating the above code in controller, flushing only Order entity

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58112/discussion-between-viko-and-broncha).